# Create table and auto increment column in Firebird with Delphi

Tags: delphi, firebird, auto-increment, unidac

I want to create table in Firebird embedded and set a column for auto increment, but I can't. I can create the table, but can't set a column for auto increment.

I am using:
Firebird embedded 2.5
Delphi xe3
UniDAC Componnent

my SQL command:

```
with UniSQL1 do
  begin
    SQL.Text := 'Create TABLE tab1(EMP_NO EMPNO NOT NULL, '+
  'FIRST_NAME           "FIRSTNAME" NOT NULL, '+
  'LAST_NAME             "LASTNAME" NOT NULL, '+
  'PHONE_EXT                VARCHAR(     4)  COLLATE NONE, '+
 'PRIMARY KEY (EMP_NO) '+
  '); '+
  'CREATE GENERATOR gen_tab1_EMP_NO; '+
  'SET GENERATOR gen_tab1_EMP_NO TO 0; '+
  'SET TERM !! ; '+
  'CREATE TRIGGER SET_EMP_NO FOR tab1 ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0 AS '+
  'BEGIN '+
      'if (new.emp_no is null) then '+
      'new.emp_no = gen_id(gen_tab1_EMP_NO, 1); '+
  'END !!'+
  'SET TERM ; !!';

    try
       Execute;
       ShowMessage('Table Created');
    except
       ShowMessage('Table Not Created');
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Please describe the problem, and show any errors you get. Also note that you are trying to execute multiple statements at once: Firebird itself doesn't allow that, so make sure that this is actually supported by the component you use (ie: it splits it in separate statements for you).

Comment: Dont forget to commit after each statement, but I dont know why are you not running these statements on a database level rather than in delphi code, because surely these statements will only be ran once.

Comment: @Fero68 It is not necessary to commit after each DDL statement, just after the entire unit of work.

Comment: @Mark you are right, provided you wrap your statements around a terminator (SET TERM)

Comment: @Fero68 I think we are talking about different things, because even that is not necessary (`SET TERM` is not actually something that is recognized by Firebird server, so that is purely tool specific).

Comment: What you mean by **I can't**? do you get an error msg? please describe your problem well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see where occurs error. You can try too save your script and execute on IBExpert or other tool and see if run properly.

```
with UniSQL1 do
begin
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('Create TABLE tab1(');
    SQL.Add(     EMP_NO EMPNO NOT NULL,');
    SQL.Add('    FIRST_NAME "FIRSTNAME" NOT NULL,');
    SQL.Add('    LAST_NAME  "LASTNAME" NOT NULL,');
    SQL.Add('    PHONE_EXT  VARCHAR(4) COLLATE NONE,');
    SQL.Add('    PRIMARY KEY (EMP_NO)');
    SQL.Add(')');
    try
        Execute;
    except
        on E:Exception do
            raise Exception.Create('ERROR 1:' + sLineBreak + E.Message);
    end;

    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('CREATE GENERATOR gen_tab1_EMP_NO;');
    try
        Execute;
    except
        on E:Exception do
            raise Exception.Create('ERROR 2:' + sLineBreak + E.Message);
    end;

    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('SET GENERATOR gen_tab1_EMP_NO TO 0;');
    try
        Execute;
    except
        on E:Exception do
            raise Exception.Create('ERROR 3:' + sLineBreak + E.Message);
    end;

    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('CREATE TRIGGER SET_EMP_NO FOR tab1 ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0 AS');
    SQL.Add('BEGIN');
    SQL.Add('    if (new.emp_no is null) then');
    SQL.Add('        new.emp_no = gen_id(gen_tab1_EMP_NO, 1);');
    SQL.Add('END'
    try
        Execute;
    except
        on E:Exception do
            raise Exception.Create('ERROR 4:' + sLineBreak + E.Message);
    end;
end;
```